# Service Worker - как создать произвести подключение по WebSocket

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, service-worker

Вопрос такой - есть туториалы по создаю ServiceWorker, но под мою задачу мне необходимо - создать Worker, который даже когда закрыта вкладка самого приложения, держал соединение с backend'ом и при необходимости принимал сообщения и показывал уведомления с помощью Notification API. Соединение подразумеваю делать через WebSocket. Можете объяснить как все это реализовать или скинуть туториалы или готовые материалы?

Comment: Дак, когда пользователь закрывает вкладку происходит `close-connection`, а когда снова открывает, то происходит `connection`. Никак не получится оставить соединение открытым, если только вы, напишите свой клиент, который после закрытия будет где-то в трее.

Comment: А по какому принципу тогда работает youtube или facebook с их уведомлениями. Ведь я подписываюсь на них и даже не открывая страницы, мне приходят уведомления о новом сообщении, видео и т.д. Как тогда решить данный вопрос?

Comment: Постоянными реконектами с тайм-аутами, только, если. И каким-нибудь блокирующим режимом.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***ServiceWorker*** не способен на работу в ***бекграунд - режиме***, ***НО*** то, что вы хотите можно осуществить. Дело в том, что существует так называемый [*Push API*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Push_API).

***Push API*** позволяет ***Service Worker'ам*** получать уведомления даже тогда, когда пользователь не находится на сайте. Работает это так: сервер отсылает ***Service Worker'ам*** сообщение через ***Push API***. На клиенте запускается ***Service Worker*** и обрабатывает событие ***onpush***, через который сервер и передаёт нужное уведомление. Затем, ***Service Worker*** показывает уведомление через ***Notification API*** ...ииии... ***профит***!

Я рекомендую ознакомиться с [*этой статьёй*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Push_API/Using_the_Push_API). В ней показано использование Push API. Переведена она не полностью, но что имеем, то имеем...

Comment: Можно ещё добавить что благодаря такой схеме мы имеем сотни сайтов, постоянно спрашивающих отправлять ли нам уведомления.

Comment: Благодарю вас, помогло!

Comment: @sanmai, эти постоянные вопросы - вина не ***PUSH API***, а ***NOTIFICATION API***.